# NIntegrate doesn't work on regional integration

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I use FEM to solve a PDE in a spherical region and I want to integrate the result within half of the spherical region.
I wonder why NIntegrate doesn't work here. The integrant should not have singularity cause the solution is finite everywhere.

```
Clear[u];
reg = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y, z}\), \(2\)]\(u[t, x, y, 
       z]\)\) == NeumannValue[0, True], 
   u[0, x, y, z] == 0.5 Tanh[30 z] + 0.5}, 
  u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg]
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && z > 0, {x, y, z}];
data = Table[
  NIntegrate[sol[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg1, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {t, .05, 1, .05}]
ListPlot[data]
```

It gives

[image]

If I use `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` it works but with low precision even when using a lot of sampling points. Is there a way to accurately evaluate this integration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `NIntegrate` -- the `sol` function gives `Indeterminate` for some points of the region `reg1`:

```
SeedRandom[343];
lsRPoints = RandomPoint[reg1, 200];
Select[Association[
  Map[# -> sol[0.1, Sequence @@ #] &, lsRPoints]], ! NumberQ[#] &]

During evaluation of In[51]:= InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {-0.928406,-0.347651,0.0901622} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.

During evaluation of In[51]:= InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {-0.676274,-0.360619,0.637002} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.

During evaluation of In[51]:= InterpolatingFunction::femdmval: Input value {-0.165827,-0.415793,0.890016} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function.

During evaluation of In[51]:= General::stop: Further output of InterpolatingFunction::femdmval will be suppressed during this calculation.

(* <|{-0.928406, -0.347651, 0.0901622} -> 
  Indeterminate, {-0.676274, -0.360619, 0.637002} -> 
  Indeterminate, {-0.165827, -0.415793, 0.890016} -> Indeterminate|> *)
```

Defining a function that, say, replaces `Indeterminate` with 0 would help `NIntegrate` to give numerical results:

```
Clear[sol2];
sol2[t_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] :=
  Block[{r},
   r = sol[t, x, y, z];
   If[NumberQ[r], r, 0]
  ];
```

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 data = Table[
   NIntegrate[sol2[t, x, y, z], {x, y, z} \[Element] reg1, 
    AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6, 
    MaxRecursion -> 4], {t, .05, 1, .05}]
 ]
(*Lots of warning messages*)

(*{280.363, {1.68084, 1.53627, 1.43274, 1.35325, 1.29053, 1.24077, 
  1.20077, 1.16844, 1.14222, 1.12142, 1.10546, 1.09276, 1.08204, 
  1.07332, 1.06635, 1.06092, 1.05636, 1.05272, 1.04979, 1.04745}}*)
```

**Remark:** Note that I am using `MaxRecursion->4` since I did not want to wait for too long...

**Remark:** Examine the messages -- they indicate some convergence problems.

Here we plot the result:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: That solves my confusion clearly. Thanks!

Comment: I also have another related confusion here. I tried to plot, or integrate, the initial condition I gave to the PDE in ```NDSolveValue``` and I did the same thing to ```sol[0,x,y,z]```. The results turned out to be different (not too much, but not exactly the same). So that means that the solution isn't forced to match the initial condition? Or it's due to inevitable numerical error?

Answer (score 4):

There is two ways you can go about this. As Anton noted, NDSolve will return `Indeterimate` for solution function evaluations that are outside of the region. This is the correct behavior for the finite element method as generally speaking no information is available beyond the boundary condition. That behavior, however, can be changed. This is explained in the [ExtrapolationHandler section of the NDSolve Finite Element Options tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1486405163).

```
Clear[u];
reg = Ball[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y, z}\), \(2\)]\(u[t, x, y, 
       z]\)\) == NeumannValue[0, True], 
      u[0, x, y, z] == 0.5 Tanh[30 z] + 0.5}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y, z} \[Element] reg, 
  "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Automatic,
              "WarningMessage" -> False}]
```

Now, the function evaluation uses extrapolation and gives no message:

```
sol[1, 2, 2, 2]
0.46176609059001855`
```

The second approach would be to use the same mesh both for `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`. First we create a boundary mesh that has an interface at `z==0`:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
s1 = OpenCascadeShape[Ball[]];
s2 = OpenCascadeShape[
   Polygon[{{-2, -2, 0}, {2, -2, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {-2, 2, 0}}]];
surface = OpenCascadeShapeFaces[s1];
innerDisk = OpenCascadeShapeIntersection[s1, s2];
boundary = OpenCascadeShapeUnion[Join[surface, {innerDisk}]];
(bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[
    boundary])["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Next, we generate the mesh:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, 
   "RegionMarker" -> {{{0, 0, -1/2}, 1}, {{0, 0, 1/2}, 2}}];
```

Let's visualize:

```
parts = Map[
  mesh["Wireframe"[ElementMarker == #[[1]], 
     "MeshElement" -> "MeshElements", 
     "ElementMeshDirective" -> 
      Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[#[[2]]]]]] &, {{1, Gray}, {2, 
    Orange}}]
```

[image]

```
Rasterize[Show[parts, PlotRange -> {All, {-0.02, 2}, All}]]
```

[image]

Solve:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[u[t, x, y, z], t] - \!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Del]\), \({x, y, z}\), \(2\)]\(u[t, x, y, 
       z]\)\) == NeumannValue[0, True], 
      u[0, x, y, z] == 0.5 Tanh[30 z] + 0.5}, 
    u, {t, 0, 1}, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]

data = Table[
  NIntegrate[If[z > 0, sol[t, x, y, z], 0], {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 6, PrecisionGoal -> 6], {t, .05, 1, .05}]
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Comment: It is very helpful to see multiple different solutions! Thanks!
Btw, could you comment on my another confusion here. I tried to plot, or integrate, the initial condition I gave to the PDE in NDSolveValue and I did the same thing to sol[0,x,y,z]. The results turned out to be different (not too much, but not exactly the same). So that means that the solution isn't forced to match the initial condition? Or it's due to inevitable numerical error?